# Error: No valid registration IDs iOS FCM

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I am working on push notifications and I followed this [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/) and I am able to send push notifications from my firebase project to my phone successfully. Now I am trying to implement sending messaging to device groups as shown in this [Google tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/device-group) .

Now, I am getting the device token using this method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
{
    let   tokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X",    $1)})
    print("deviceToken: \(tokenString)")
}
```

and I am trying to add it to a device group (on the server side) like so:

```
public static String addDeviceToGroup(String userKeyName, List<String> deviceToken, String notificationKey) throws IOException, JSONException {

    String result = "";
    URL url = new URL(API_URL_FCM_GROUP);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + AUTH_KEY_FCM);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestProperty("project_id", SENDER_ID);

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("registration_ids",deviceToken);
    json.put("operation","add");
    json.put("notification_key_name",userKeyName.trim());
    json.put("notification_key",notificationKey.trim());

    try {
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(
                conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(json.toString());
        wr.flush();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.print("RESPONSE CODE in addDeviceToGroup IS: " + responseCode  + "\n");
        BufferedReader br = null;
        if (responseCode == 200)
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        else
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        result = SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        result = FAILURE;
    }
    System.out.println("FCM Notification added device to group successfully RESULT IS " + result);

    return result;
}
```

I keep getting 400 as the response code and I keep getting this error:

```
{"error":"no valid registration ids"}
```

I also get the same error when trying to remove from deviceGroup.

EDIT: However, when I get the token with this:

```
let secondToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token()!
```

the token is added to device group successfully and when I send user msg to the notification key belonging to the device, in my console it shows it is delivered:

```
{"success":2,"failure":0}
```

but it does not pop up on my device.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you still need help with this but in order to get rid of the error you have to put the devicetoken in an array.

```
  let postparameters = ["operation": "create",
                          "notification_key_name": name,
                          "registration_ids": [devicetoken]] as [String : Any]
```